# AdventureWorks- finding products perform compared to the previous year

Tags: sql, adventureworks

I am using AdventureWorks2014 and I am trying to write an SQL query  that will show how the products perform compared to the previous year.

so I need to understand how to connect the year of sale to the total amount for each product.
I started by finding the years :

```
SELECT
    YEAR(oh.OrderDate) as SaleYear
FROM 
    SalesOrderDetail od 
INNER JOIN 
    SalesOrderHeader oh ON od.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID 
GROUP BY
       YEAR(oh.OrderDate);
```

but the rest of the info I don't understand, can you please help me ?

thanks,
Moni

Comment: Keep trying...use SUM(LineTotal) in the Select

Comment: but what is the field in the AdventureWorks2014  that is the LineTotal?

Comment: See this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124879%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: I tried this sqript - do you think that answering my question? is that the data I am looking for ? :SELECT  p.Name AS ProductName,
             Sum(((OrderQty*UnitPrice)*(1-UnitPriceDiscount))) AS 'Total income',
YEAR(oh.OrderDate)
FROM
 ((Product AS p INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetail AS sod ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID )
INNER JOIN SalesOrderHeader AS oh ON sod.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID)GROUP BY  p.Name ,
YEAR(oh.OrderDate)
;

Comment: This is what you want.....   SELECT p.Name AS ProductName,
  YEAR(oh.OrderDate), 
  SUM(((OrderQty*UnitPrice)*(1-UnitPriceDiscount))) AS 'Total income'
FROM Production.Product AS p 
 INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS oh ON sod.SalesOrderID = oh.SalesOrderID
GROUP BY p.Name, YEAR(oh.OrderDate)
ORDER BY p.Name, YEAR(oh.OrderDate)

Comment: thanks :) but its not the same as I wrote above you in the comments ?